# How can I replace multiple line breaks with a single <BR>?

Tags: c#, regex, editor

I am replacing all occurances of `\n` with the `<BR>` tag, but for some reason the text entered has many `\n` in a row, so I need to combine them.

Basically, if more than 1 \n occur together, replace it with just a single <BR> tag.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Don't underestimate yourself. If you even know what a regex is, you probably know the answer to this question already.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This will replace any sequence of carriage-returns (`\r`) and/or linefeeds (`\n`) with a single `<br />`:

```
string formatted = Regex.Replace(original, @"[\r\n]+", "<br />");
```

If you only want to replace sequences of two or more items then the simplistic answer is to use the `{2,}` quantifier (which means "at least two repetitions") instead of `+` (which means "at least one repetition"):

```
string formatted = Regex.Replace(original, @"[\r\n]{2,}", "<br />");
```

Note that the expression above will treat the common CR+LF combination as a sequence of two items. It's probable that you'll want to treat CR+LF as a single item instead, in which case the expression becomes slightly more complicated:

```
string formatted = Regex.Replace(original, @"(?:\r\n|\r(?!\n)|(?<!\r)\n){2,}", "<br />");
```

Comment: \r is for carriage returns.  In Windows (DOS) formatted text, you'll see carriage return/line feed combinations in the form of \r\n.

Comment: would it be possible to set a minimum of 2 repeats before a replacement?

Comment: Yes, that's what my answer was an attempt to do.  \n\n+ will do it.  But if you want carriage returns included then this will work instead: (\r\n)(\r\n)+

Comment: That would only work for Windows/DOS style text (requiring both).  Depending on your regex engine, something like: s/(?:\r|\n|\r\n){2}/<br/>/ would work.

Comment: @Bruce: Your regex will treat `\r\n` as a sequence of two rather than a single item. See the third regex in my answer, which handles `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`, and treats each of them as a single item.

Comment: @Luke Why is there a `<` character in the 3rd segment?

Comment: @smallatom: You've found a typo that's been sitting here for over five years! It's part of a [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion, but it should've read `?<!` rather than `?!<`. I've just edited to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[\r\n]+", "<br />");
```

It could well be faster to call the normal `Replace` method multiple times and not use a Regex at all, like this:

```
int oldLength;
do {
    oldLength = str.Length;
    str = str.Replace('\r', '\n');
    str = str.Replace("\n\n", "\n");
} while(str.Length != oldLength);

str = str.Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

Answer (score -2):

Note that string.Replace() is much faster than using RegEx:

```
string result = oldString.Replace("\n\n","\n");
result = result .Replace("\n","<br>");
```

Comment: This won't handle three newlines; you need to call it in a loop.  See my answer.